# Using Two Tables in PHP & MySQL to display one loop result

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so a bit of a funny question here. I have two tables: -

- LiveTable
- ArchiveTable

The data is as follows: -

```
Table: LiveTable            Table: ArchiveTable

| ID | NAME      |          | ID | NAME      |
------------------          ------------------
|  1 | Test One  |          |  4 | Test Four |
------------------          ------------------
|  2 | Test Two  |          |  5 | Test Five |
------------------          ------------------
|  3 | Test Three|          |  6 | Test Six  |
```

What I want to do is merge them into one table for querying purposes only. Not as a Database Structure.

In essence when I do a PHP Loop I want the results to work like this: -

```
Merged Results

| ID | NAME      |
------------------
|  1 | Test One  |
------------------
|  2 | Test Two  |
------------------
|  3 | Test Three|
------------------
|  4 | Test Four |
------------------
|  5 | Test Five |
------------------
|  6 | Test Six  |
```

How would I go about doing this? Also is there a way of doing this with Doctrine?

Comment: print ist array than second array or use array_merge()

Comment: Create view Using those two tables;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SQL query with `UNION`:

```sql
SELECT ID, Name
FROM LiveTable            

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, Name
FROM ArchiveTable
```

**Note:** `UNION ALL` will retain duplicates. If you want to remove duplicate records, then use `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Yould use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

```
SELECT id, name FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name FROM tbl2
```

Answer (score 1):

Create DB view using above two tables

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT 
  id, name FROM tbl1
UNION
  id, name FROM tbl2
```

Then you can query on your view

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sql query multi table select

```
Select * from LiveTable,ArchiveTable
```

that's it